# Error C3861: "is_valid" identifier not found when using CGAL as a header-only library in Visual Studio C++ project

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, compiler-errors, cgal

I'm encountering an error in my Visual Studio C++ project when using CGAL library. The error message I'm getting is:

**Error C3861 "is_valid": identifier not found. Lib C:**\CGAL-5.5.2\include\CGAL\long_double.h 149**

Here are the steps I followed to include CGAL in my existing project:

1. I downloaded the CGAL-5.5.2 zip file from the official GitHub repository at https://github.com/CGAL/cgal/releases/tag/v5.5.2.
2. I extracted the contents of the zip file and replaced the "auxiliary" folder with the one from the "GMP and MPFR libraries, for Windows 64bits.zip" file, as mentioned in the documentation.
3. In Visual Studio, I added "CGAL-5.5.2\auxiliary\gmp\include" and "CGAL-5.5.2\include" as additional include directories.
4. I also added "CGAL-5.5.2\auxiliary\gmp\lib" as an additional library directory.
5. Finally I added libgmp-10.lib and libmpfr-4.lib as additional linking dependencies.

As a result I included CGAL as a header-only library in my existing Visual Studio C++ project **without** executing `cmake`, because the documentation says:

> Since version 5.0, CGAL is a header-only library, meaning that it is no longer needed to build CGAL libraries before it can be used.

However, when I try to build my project, I'm getting the following error:
**Error C3861 "is_valid": identifier not found. Lib C:**\CGAL-5.5.2\include\CGAL\long_double.h 149**

I have discovered that manually setting the `CGAL_CFG_IEEE_754_BUG` preprocessor macro resolves the issue, but I am hesitant to configure such settings manually. My concern arises from the fact that this configuration is not mentioned anywhere in the documentation, and I am unsure if it could potentially lead to other "hard-to-diagnose" issues in the future. It was during my search for the definition of "is_valid" that I came across the `CGAL_CFG_IEEE_754_BUG` macro.

I would greatly appreciate any advice or suggestions on how to resolve this error and successfully use CGAL as a header-only library in my Visual Studio C++ project without the need for manual configuration.

I am looking for a reliable and documented approach to ensure the correct usage of CGAL in my Visual Studio C++ project.

Thank you for your assistance!

Comment: I thought that `CGAL_CFG_IEEE_754_BUG` gets set (or not set) by `cmake` when it builds the `compiler_config.h` file.

Comment: @Eljay maybe it does too, but as mentioned before, I don't run cmake because I just include CGAL in my project folder as heder-only library. I don't install CGAL using cmake.

Comment: *I don't install CGAL using cmake.*  But you do configure CGAL using cmake, right?

Comment: @Eljay No, I don't do anything with cmake. Should I?

Comment: It will probably be easier to have CGAL self-configure, rather than try to configure it by hand through trial-and-error.

Comment: @Eljay I understand that regardless of whether I include CGAL in my project as header-only or precompiled, I should always run cmake beforehand for configuration.